# How do I lock the white balance in AVfoundation for swift?

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to lock my iPhone back facing camera's white balance to its current state but I am having trouble from the point of converting objective-c code to swift. This is the code in objective-c:

```
[device setWhiteBalanceMode:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeLocked];
```

this is what I thought the code in swift should look like:

```
captureDevice.setWhiteBalanceMode(AVCaptureWhiteBalanceMode.Locked)
```

and Xcode tells me this:

```
'AVCaptureDevice' does not have a member named 'setWhiteBalanceMode'
```

Comment: You should award the answer to the person who spent the time and made the effort to give you the proper answer!

Answer (score 5):

```
        if captureDevice.lockForConfiguration(nil) {
            var gains: AVCaptureWhiteBalanceGains = AVCaptureWhiteBalanceGainsCurrent
            captureDevice.setWhiteBalanceModeLockedWithDeviceWhiteBalanceGains(gains, completionHandler:nil);
            captureDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
        }
```